# Onclick closing a DIV loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am loading my content with ajax on a wordpress website this way:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(".post-link").click(function(){
            var post_link = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#single-post-container").show().html("content loading");
        $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
        return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

This works fine, but when I try to add a function to a button to close this DIV nothing happens:

```
<script>
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#single-post-container").hide();
    });
</script>
```

So first I do "show" and after that I want to close it with "hide" but it is not working, no matter if the button is inside or outside of the ajax loaded DIV.

Comment: Where is the button with ID hide? If it is loaded dynamically, you need to find one of the MANY event delegation answers

Comment: The button is inside the loaded DIV. I can't even add a class to the loaded DIV with jquery … .

Comment: See my updated comment. It makes a huge difference if the button is in the loaded html or not

Comment: It doesn't even work the button is outside the loaded DIV.

Comment: That is unlikely. Post the html and show where you assign the click handler

Comment: Now I see the loaded content doesn't show up in the source code, I only see it with firebug. Maybe this is the Problem (but i see the loaded content in the Browser).

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted you HTML but the following must apply:

1. something with ID `single-post-container` must exist at page load time and only one of them (unique ID)
2. something with ID `hide` must exist at page load time and only one of them
3. the button must have `type="button"` or it will attempt to submit the page to itself

If 1 but not 2, and `hide` is loaded into the container you need

```
$(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
  $(".post-link").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#single-post-container").show().html("content loading");
    $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
  });
  $("#single-post-container").on("click","#hide",function(){
    $("#single-post-container").hide();
  });
});
```

If 1 AND 2 and `hide` is outside the container:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
  $(".post-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#single-post-container").show().html("content loading");
    $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
  });
  $("#hide").on("click",function(){
    $("#single-post-container").hide();
  });
});
```